# Create Sidebar with Multi-selection Checkbox that Puts Value into Selected Cell

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, spreadsheet

I'm using a Google spreadsheet and want to create a sidebar menu with multiple check boxes and button. When selection 1 is selected or check box is clicked, and user presses Enter, the values from check boxes should display in the selected cell in the spreadsheet.

Comment: Read this documentation, and use the sample code.  [Custom Sidebars - Google Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#custom_sidebars)  Get that sample to work, and then modify the HTML to add what you want.  Do a search on HTML check box, and add that to the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

There is an input type of checkbox:

```
<form action="">
  <input type="checkbox" name="myCategory" value="Yes">I like toast<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="myCategoryTwo" value="No">Don't like toast
</form>
```

### gs Code

```
function onOpen() {

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
      .createMenu('Custom Menu')
      .addItem('Show sidebar', 'showSidebar')
      .addToUi();
};
```

### gs Server code To Create Dialog

```
function showSidebar() {
  Logger.log('showSidebar ran: ' );

  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Dialog')
    .evaluate()
    .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
    .setTitle('My custom sidebar')
    .setWidth(300);

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    .showSidebar(html);
}
```

### HTML

```
<div>

  <form action="">
    <input id="idYesChk" type="checkbox" name="myCategory" value="Yes">I like toast<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="myCategoryTwo" value="No">Don't like toast
  </form>

  <input type="text">

  <input type='button' value="Update Spreadsheet" onclick='fncCallServerToDoSomething()'>
</div>

<script>

  function fncCallServerToDoSomething() {
    console.log('fncCallServerToDoSomething ran!');

    var aReturnedValue = document.getElementById("idYesChk").value;

    console.log("value of check box: " + aReturnedValue);

    google.script.run
      .withFailureHandler(onFailure)
      .gsFunctionToRun(aReturnedValue);

    //google.script.host.close();
  };

  function onFailure(error) {
    console.log(error.message);
  };
</script>
```

### gs Code To write value to Spreadsheet

**Puts Value Into Active Cell**

```
function gsFunctionToRun(argValueRetrieved) {
  Logger.log('argValueRetrieved: ' + argValueRetrieved);

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var theSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  var activeCell = ss.getActiveCell().getA1Notation();
  var theRange = theSheet.getRange(activeCell);

  theRange.setValue(argValueRetrieved);
};
```

**Puts Value into Range (cell) Designated**

```
function gsFunctionToRun(argValueRetrieved) {
  Logger.log('argValueRetrieved: ' + argValueRetrieved);

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var theSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  var theRange = theSheet.getRange("B4");
  theRange.setValue(argValueRetrieved);

};
```